# Как сделать данную работу с помощью CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите сделать данную работу с помощью css, как должно это выглядеть, как обернуть весь текст в темно зеленый фон?

Answer (score 0):

ну вы совсем блин даёте

в чём же сложность?

```css
body {
  background: #014242;
}

.text {
  margin: 50px;
  width:  calc(100% - 2 * 50px);
  
  color:  #ffffff;
  font-size:  42px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'text'>Как сделать данную работу с помощью CSS</div>
```

Comment: на изображении четко видны элементы, я просил как выполнить данное задание со всеми элементами, а не только бэкграунд к боди добавить с h1!

Comment: мне кажется это вы издеваетесь - читаем внимательно ваше задание `как обернуть весь текст в темно зеленый фон?` - я правильно понял ваш вопрос - обернуть текст в тёмно зелёный фон? или вам надо расположить правильно все элементы, точно подобрать шрифт, который там используется и т.д.? если так, то наверное стоило более точно описать задание, не находите?